# How to call Overrides Sub OnCellParsing from another event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2012 and trying to learn the tricks of coading, kindly help on **how to call** Protected Overrides Sub OnCellParsing(e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs) **from** 'If Me.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(5) Then'

Comment: Firstly, if you want to learn the tricks of coading then you should learn the spelling of "coding".  As for the question, the answer is that you don't.  `OnCellParsing` is invoked when a cell contents requires parsing and it raises the `CellParsing` event.  You don;t call it directly.  Maybe if you were to describe what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it, we could suggest a correct way.

Comment: Thanks  jmcilhinney,
I have a Protected Sub OnCellParcing which is automatically called when the CellContent is changed, but, sometimes it is missed.  And, to be sure that it is always called I want to call it like other Private Sub can be called to execute the event.

Comment: create a procedure called `ParseThisSCell` put all the coad/code there for the functionality you want to invoke. then just call it from whereever you need that functionality. code can exist in places other than events

Comment: Thanks Plutonix
I did like this:

    Private Sub ParseThisSCell()
        OnCellParsing(CType(Me(8, CurrentRow.Index).Value, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs))
    End Sub

And it gave the following error message:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs'."